# Cross Product in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

**Question:** Find the area of a triangle with **base 10 and height 6** using cross product in complex analysis.

**Approach:** I know that $$\mathbf{a\times b}=\mathbf{||a||\cdot||b||}\sin \theta\mathbf{n}$$
$$\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}= \begin{vmatrix}
\mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
\end{vmatrix}.$$

But how do I use this to find the area of the triangle above? Can someone assist me?

Comment: cross product in the complex plane? sounds strange, moreover taking into account that the cross product of two vectors must be perpendicular to both, so a definition like that doesn't seem to make sense in a bidimensional plane like $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @NateRiver... Yeah! In a complex plane. Do you have any idea of how to approach this?

Comment: Not by myself. However, *if you see the complex plane as $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$*, this video could be useful (and the question would make sense): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A85_qJ5P5ik

Comment: @NateRiver... I have watched series of such videos on finding area of a triangle formed by two vectors using cross products and even googled as such. But for this problem, no vectors or vertices are defined.

Comment: Well, you can see each point $z=x+iy\in \mathbb{C}$ as a vector $z=(x,y)$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, or even better, as a vector $z=(x,y,0)$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and apply the method of the video to those vectors.